# SQL case statement - 3 clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-concatenation

hopefully someone can help with this

I have  a table that looks like the below

```
ID | Name | Age | GroupID | Services
33 | Pam  | 34  |  334    |   3
33 | Pam  | 34  |  334    |   4
43 | Lily | 56  |  10     |   3
67 | Bob  | 22  |  11     |   4
```

Notice how Pam has 2 rows as she has 2 different types of services.

How would I write a case statement that would bring  out whether the person in the Name column has either service 3, service 4 or both.

For example my output when querying the above would be

```
 ID | Name | Age | GroupID | Services | SG
    33 | Pam  | 34  |  334    |   3   | 3 & 4
    33 | Pam  | 34  |  334    |   4   | 3 & 4
    43 | Lily | 56  |  10     |   3   | 3 Only
    67 | Bob  | 22  |  11     |   4   | 4 Only
```

Thank you all as always

Comment: Can we assume that is someone belongs to 3, that the return should be 3, 4, & 5? This means you need to introduce a way to (excuse the made up word) "grammarise" the returned dataset. This isn't really SQL Server's forté.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

### Edit: added `DISTINCT` to avoid cases of `3 & 4 & 4`

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100),Age INT, GroupID INT,[Services] INT);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
  (33,'Pam',34,334,3)
 ,(33,'Pam',34,334,4)
 ,(43,'Lily',56,10,3)
 ,(67,'Bob',22,11,4);

 SELECT t.*
       ,STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ' & ' + CAST(x.[Services] AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM @mockupTable AS x
            WHERE t.ID=x.ID 
            ORDER BY x.[Services]
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,3,'') AS SG
 FROM @mockupTable AS t;
```

The result

```
+----+------+-----+---------+----------+--------------------+
| ID | Name | Age | GroupID | Services | SG                 |
+----+------+-----+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 33 | Pam  | 34  | 334     | 3        | 3 & 4              |
+----+------+-----+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 33 | Pam  | 34  | 334     | 4        | 3 & 4              |
+----+------+-----+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 43 | Lily | 56  | 10      | 3        | 3                  |
+----+------+-----+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 67 | Bob  | 22  | 11      | 4        | 4                  |
+----+------+-----+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

This is the query if you want to add the  `only`:

```
SELECT t.*
        ,STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ' & ' + CAST(x.[Services] AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM @mockupTable AS x
            WHERE t.ID=x.ID 
            ORDER BY x.[Services]
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,3,'') 
        + CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) = 1 THEN ' Only' ELSE '' END AS SG
    FROM @mockupTable AS t;
```

Comment: I am not convinced that distinct is a good idea. In case of having the same service multiple times, this should probably be reflected in the output. But hopefully the combination of id and services has a unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have just two services 3 and 4 and it can never happen that the same person has the same service twice then I would use

```
select *, case when (count(*) over (partition by name)) = 2 then '3 & 4' 
          else cast(services as varchar) + ' Only' end
from t
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0ea0c0eb6a5e06870a8cc070e34d3db0)

Comment: This won't return the expected result if you have 2 entries for the Same Person with the Same Service. Suppose I have entries for Id 1 and Service 3 twice and there is no Service 4, it will still say 3&4

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh true, I have updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
SELECT
    *,
    SG = CASE Q.Cnt
        WHEN 1 THEN '3 & 4' 
       ELSE CAST(T1.[Services] AS VARCHAR(10))+' Only' END
    FROM YourTable T1
       OUTER APPLY
       (
          SELECT
             Cnt = COUNT(DISTINCT Srv)
             FROM YourTable T2
                WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id
                    AND t2.[Services]  IN (3,4)
                    AND t2.[Services] <> t1.[Services]
       )Q
```

Comment: In this case he needs only 3&4 and this is the most easiest way that I can think of

Comment: Well, but its pretty obvious, that this should be actual values carried by the work load...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ---

Note-**USE CHARINDEX for adding 'Only' Text at the end.**

```
;WITH CTE1 AS 
(
    select 33 id , 'Pam' Name , 34 Age ,  334 GroupBy   ,   3 Services
    union all
    select 33 , 'Pam'  , 34  ,  334    ,   4
    union all
    select 43 , 'Lily' , 56  ,  10     ,   3
    union all
    select 67 , 'Bob'  , 22  ,  11     ,   4
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT * ,
                  STUFF 
                    ((
                        SELECT CONCAT(' & ' , Services ) Services
                        FROM CTE1 a
                        WHERE ( a.id = b.id )
                        FOR XML PATH(''),Type
                    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,2,'') 
                    AS SG
    FROM CTE1 b
)
SELECT Id,Name,Age,GroupBy,Services , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',SG,0) = 0 THEN CONCAT(SG,' Only') ELSE SG END SG 
FROM CTE2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Id          Name Age         GroupBy     Services    SG
----------- ---- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------
33          Pam  34          334         3            3 & 4
33          Pam  34          334         4            3 & 4
43          Lily 56          10          3            3 Only
67          Bob  22          11          4            4 Only

(4 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with MS SQL2017, this one should do the trick:

```
WITH A AS
(
    SELECT
            ID, Name, Age, GroupID,
            STRING_AGG (Services, ' & ')
    FROM yourtable 
    GROUP BY ID, Name, Age, GroupID
)
SELECT DISTINCT
        A.ID, A.Name, A.Age, B.Services,
        CASE 
         WHEN LEN(A.SG) = 1 THEN A.SG + ' Only'
         ELSE A.SG
        END AS SG
FROM yourtable AS B
LEFT JOIN A
    ON A.ID = B.ID
```